# .NET Odata 7.2 > dynamic IEdmModel using dependency injection

Tags: dynamic, frameworks, odata, entity

Build a dynamic odata endpoint using .NET oData 7.2. I am injecting the IEdmModel using a DI per scope request for each request - so that my dynamic endpoint can change Model per URL i.e. /odata/modela/$metadata and /odata/modelb/$metadata returns two different models.

Inspiration came from https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation

Injecting the model using the following works:

```
.AddService<IEdmModel>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => GetModelBasedOnUrl());
```

If I change the lifetime from singleton to scoped (allowing custom model for each request), the EdmModel renders an error as it is not cached; invoking an exception

```
"message": "An resource with type 'ns.ModelA' was found, but it is not assignable to the expected type 'ns.ModelA'. The type specified in the resource must be equal to either the expected type or a derived type.",
            "type": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
            "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.OData.ValidationUtils.ValidateEntityTypeIsAssignable(IEdmEntityTypeReference expectedEntityTypeReference, IEdmEntityTypeReference payloadEntityTypeReference)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.WriterValidator.ValidateTypeReference(IEdmTypeReference typeReferenceFromMetadata, IEdmTypeReference typeReferenceFromValue)\r\n
```

It seems like the ODataWriterCore need a persistant data source.

Anyone got a solution how to make service lifetime singleton across the Odata request pipeline ?

Comment: Are the `modela` and `modelb` URL segments dynamic as well, or do you have a fixed number of possible URLs that could be created statically?